# How can i combine location based service in passbook ios6?

Tags: ios6, passbook

I see

> Passbook can use location and time data to launch the passes when the app believes you will want to use them.

in apple doc.

So can i send push notification when my customers approach a particular location? If yes, how can i do it?
Is there any tutorial online?

Thx

Comment: I can add 'locations' and 'relevantDate' to display relevant information on lock screen, not push notification.

Answer (score 1):

In your pass.json file add location tag also

```
"locations" : [
        {"latitude" : 8.5682,
            "longitude" : 76.87349,
            "relevantText" : "Store nearby on 3rd and Main."}

    ],
```

Change the iphone general location settings to ON

Go through apples programming guide

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH4-SW53

Answer (score 0):

In short, No. This is because Passbook does not make any callbacks when a location alert is triggered.

Apple refer to location alerts as 'passive alerts'. Their purpose is to recognise that the user may need the pass and to make it available to him. There is no direct or indirect data that will tell us that a location alert has been triggered and certainly nothing that could trigger a push notification.