# How to get geofencing didEnterRegion delegate method call when app is closed

Tags: ios, simulation, geofencing

So when the app is closed (not in background, but totally closed), how app can get didEnterRegion delegate method call when user enter a region? And how I can simulate that in simulator.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app will be reopened (into the background) to handle the update. You can not test this in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator go to the 'Debug :: Location' submenu and either select a test location or enter lat+long data under 'Custom Location...'

If your application is not running, then it can't get location services.  However, if you can add a 'Passbook' aspect to your Application then you can get Passbook to monitor a location for you.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040276/1286639

Answer (score 0):

If you use region monitoring, your app will be restarted by the system.
It's hard to debug because when you close the app, the debugger will detach.

Try this:
Start the app on a connected phone and simulate new locations using Xcode. To do this, create a GPX file with multiple locations. When the debugger is running, there is a little location arrow next to the start/stop/pause buttons that allows you to select the GPX file with your track. Xcode will then simulate moving from point to point in the GPX. You can verify this by opening the Maps app and watching the location move around.

When you kill your app, the debugger will detach, but you can reattach with Debug->Attach to process->Your App Name. That will get you the console back, but you won't be able to continue simulating the location in the running app. Also it's not clear if the simulated location resets back to normal mode when you do this. I get different results all the time.

Region monitoring is flaky at best. I have been trying to get reliable results since iOS 5 and it's a real mess with unpredictable results...